# ms graph API - how to check out a file using the graph client in c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to replicate these tested (and working) queries using MSGraph Explorer in a c# application using graph client:

HTTP Request in Graph explorer to check out a (sharepoint) file:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mySuperCoolDomainName.sharepoint.com,555b5555-5555-4555-5bb5-b555b55555b5,5555b555b-1234-123b1-83de-55b55b55555/lists/12345ccc-1c9c-1c11-9e09-1cc1234bb0b4/items/2/driveItem/checkout
```

In the query above, I'm assuming site ID is :

```
mySuperCoolDomainName.sharepoint.com,555b5555-5555-4555-5bb5-b555b55555b5,5555b555b-1234-123b1-83de-55b55b55555
```

Drive Id is:

```
12345ccc-1c9c-1c11-9e09-1cc1234bb0b4
```

*Problem*

When I try to checkout the file in my c# application, I'm getting the following error:

> Message: The provided drive id appears to be malformed, or does not
> represent a valid drive.

**c# code**

```
string mySiteId = "mySuperCoolDomainName.sharepoint.com,555b5555-5555-4555-5bb5-b555b55555b5,5555b555b-1234-123b1-83de-55b55b55555";
string sharedDocsDriveId = "12345ccc-1c9c-1c11-9e09-1cc1234bb0b4";
string sharedFile.Id = "2";

await App.GraphClient.Sites[mySiteId].Drives[sharedDocsDriveId].Items[sharedFile.Id]
   .Checkout()
   .Request()
   .PostAsync();
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

Since this is a shared document list in sharepoint, I also tried changing the Drives method to Lists like this:

```
            */
        await App.GraphClient.Sites[mySiteId].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId].Items[sharedFile.Id]
            .Checkout()
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();
```

But I get an error that there's no Checkout() method:

```
Error
CS1061
'IListItemRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Checkout' and no accessible extension method 'Checkout' accepting a first argument of type 'IListItemRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
            await App.GraphClient.Sites[mySiteId].Lists[sharedDocsDriveId].Items[sharedFile.Id].DriveItem
                .Checkout()
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
```